# Recover WhatsApp chat history using crypt14 file

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I tried to restore WhatsApp chat history using the crypt14 file following the steps on the WhatsApp page (https://faq.whatsapp.com/6181521285295518/?helpref=hc_fnav&cms_platform=android&cms_id=6181521285295518&draft=true), the backup file is detected by WhatsApp, the restoration process ends, but at the end a message appears stating that it was not possible to restore the conversation history. Can someone help me please? I even tried to put other folders from the WhatsApp folder that I had saved in the WhatsApp folder (Media, Backups, etc.), but it still didn't work. I don't have a backup on Google Drive, so there is no such restore option. Thanks in advance.